# Save bitmap to BMP image in windows 8 app c#

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-7, windows-8

I need help turning a bitmap image into a .BMP file in an windows 8 app. I have looked around the internet with no good results on how to accomplish this.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Didn't heard that there a solution for .BMP format. BMP is really easy in saving by hand, you can do it by self. Only two easy headers and array of bytes. This library can help you to accomplish that task: [WriteableBitmapEx](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/). There are functions to save TGA and uncompressed PNG. Use them to build the BMP saver.